# Sample code of IBM Watson Discovery News

Tags: python, watson-discovery

After reading the Watson API reference and playing around the Watson Discovery News Demo, I came out with the code below trying to replicate the function that the IBM Watson Discovery News demo [Sentiment Analysis] can perform. But unfortunately my code can't get the same responses as the demo returns.

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1

# --- Authentication ----
discovery = DiscoveryV1(
    username="581xxxx-5c55-xxxx-983f-027xxxxxxxxx",
    password="xxxxxxxxxx",
    version="2017-11-07"
)

qopts = {"query": "\"tesla\"",
  "filter": "language:(english|en),crawl_date>2017-10-14T12:00:00-
  0700,crawl_date<2017-12-14T12:00:00-0800",
  "aggregations": [
      "term(host).term(enriched_text.sentiment.document.label)",
      "term(enriched_text.sentiment.document.label)"
  ]
}

my_query = discovery.query('system', 'news-en', qopts)
print(json.dumps(my_query, indent=2))
```

Can someone kindly help me by showing a sample python code that can perform the query as the IBM demo does? For example, a simple code that can return the same responses as the demo [Sentiment Analysis] given the query "Tesla" ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your qopts to look like this:

```
qopts = {"query": "\"tesla\"",
  "filter": "language:(english|en),crawl_date>2017-10-14T12:00:00-
  0700,crawl_date<2017-12-14T12:00:00-0800",
  "aggregations": "[term(host).term(enriched_text.sentiment.document.label),term(enriched_text.sentiment.document.label)]"
}
```

Comment: @AlbertH they aren't the same. the `"` and `[`,`]` are transposed.

Comment: dear @atambo , thanks for your commend. yes, agreed, the spelling of our qopts are slightly different. But they all generate the same response which seemly not correct. Using the API on IBM Watson discover news demo site, the return is simply like { "sentiment": { "type": "term", "field": "enriched_text.sentiment.document.label", "results": [....}, while using the python SDK as we discussed, the return is quite meaningless. I guess my question should be specified as How to get the "filter" and "aggregation" work correctly? Truly hope someone can show me a correct sample. Thanks.